# How does one make a VIM window a full on terminal?

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run a terminal inside of vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236563/how-to-run-a-terminal-inside-of-vim)

I can setup my workspace nicely with split and vsplit and open... but I would
like to simply use one of the splits as a terminal window.  I know opening an
additional xterm and placing it strategically might be able to accomplish this
but many times I am telneted into a single window and my hands are beginning to hurt
from alt tabbing between terminals.

Update:  The best thing I came up with based on the suggestions below was to use screen and actually have vim occupy one of its windows.

Comment: I think you ought to try out ConqueTerm. 
https://github.com/rson/vim-conque

Screen's great but ConqueTerm is really well implemented. (in my opinion)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider running Vim and a shell together in [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).  The [Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/GNU_Screen_integration) has info on integrating Vim and Screen.  Screen supports splitting into "windows" similar to Vim's.  See [here](http://technotales.wordpress.com/2007/10/03/like-slime-for-vim/) for an example of even tighter Vim+Screen integration.

Having a Vim buffer tied directly to an external interactive commandline app is a feature that many have wanted for a long time, but apparently it's a bit difficult to do, due to how Vim is implemented, and the Vim devs are reluctant to change this (for arguably good reasons).

But there have been a few success stories.  The Lisp community in particular has tried to reproduce Emacs' SLIME (an interactive Lisp prompt) in Vim.  See [VimClojure](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2501) and [Limp](http://mikael.jansson.be/hacking/limp/docs/) for examples.  One of those could probably be altered to run a shell, but it'd take some work.

Answer (score 14):

I use : http://code.google.com/p/conque/wiki/Usage

You can type :split new  and the :ConqueTerm bash. And you have a working terminal window. :)

Comment: This was the exactly solution I was finally happy with.

I tried the screen solution, the vimshell solution; but my final personal preference is ConqueTerm.

Answer (score 8):

The [vimshell](http://www.wana.at/vimshell/) patch sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: Tried it but not too great. It doesn't support non-ncurses packages.

Comment: The link is dead now, it redirects to an index page on the same domain.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in vim, you can exit to a sub-shell with the ":sh" command, and then get back to vim with "exit".  Or you can just suspend vim and go back to the original shell you started it from with control-Z, then go back to vim with "fg" (foreground).

Or there is an ["vim-shell"](http://www.wana.at/vimshell/) add-on you can install.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on [Brian Carper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671583/how-does-one-make-a-vim-window-a-full-on-terminal/671615#671615), you could throw this into your
`~/.screenrc`:

```
startup_message off
# Launch 2 screens on startup
split
# Have bash login so $PATH will be updated
screen -t Vim bash -l -c 'vim' 0
focus
screen -t canvas bash -l
# switch focus back to vim
focus up
```

Then when you type `screen`, you'll have a Vim window on top and
a bash window on the bottom. You can switch between screen windows with
`<C-a><Tab>`.

Answer (score 2):

conque shell for vim does this too.

[image]

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771

http://code.google.com/p/conque/

Comment: This is useful! One thing that I don't know how to do (looking at your screenshot you're doing it but with Python instead of Ruby) is that I want to run my test suite using an existing utility when I save a file. It works, but if I'm not in INSERT MODE in that window, it won't write the STDOUT of the utility to the buffer so I have to go in to that window every time and hit `i` to see what specs failed. Do you know of a way to get the window to always write out the utility's STDOUT to the buffer even when not in INSERT MODE? Cheers!

Comment: I just found `let g:ConqueTerm_ReadUnfocused = 1` which does just that. Unfortunately it says that due to certain scripting limitations with VIM, it won't allow for scrolling with the Window in a non-focussed state. Too bad. :/

Answer (score -3):

You will have to forgo this I'm afraid - no way to do it in vim.

Comment: Each of the 5 other answers all present reasonable solutions.