# How to temporarily exit Vim and go back

Tags: vim

How could I exit Vim, not `:q`, and then go back to continue editing?

Answer (score 677, accepted):

Assuming terminal Vim on a flavor of *nix:

### To suspend your running Vim

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

will suspend the process and get back to your shell

```
fg
```

will resume (bring to **f**ore**g**round) your suspended Vim.

### To start a new shell

Start a subshell using:

```
:sh
```

(as configured by)

```
:set shell?
```

### or

```
:!bash
```

followed by:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (or `exit`, but why type so much?)

to kill the shell and return to Vim.

Comment: `ps` to view foreground processes http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/viewing-foreground-process-using-ps

Comment: What if I want to continue running my server while editing my file. For example, let's say I do `nodemon app.js` (nodemon refreshes the server on file edits for you) and then I want to return to my vim editing. Can I do that without two separate terminal windows?

Comment: or `jobs` to visit the foreground processes with a (to me) more readable title. Then eg `fg %2` to select the second.

Comment: If this isn't working for you and `control-z` acts as 'undo' check your vimrc to see if `behave mswin` is present.  If it is remove it and `control-z` will work

Comment: Is there a way to prevent vim from auto-saving the file if you suspended vim or do I have some configuration that's doing this?

Comment: Works for Windows users too! `:sh` or `Ctrl+Z` will start (a new) command prompt.

Comment: in windows you can get back to vim if you type `exit`

Comment: so many plugins, formatters, etc break when you use Ctrl+Z.   don't do it.

Comment: Does this work on windows cause. `ctrl+z `is starting a new shell as per the info provide by the CLI. However `fg` is not bringing anything to foregrund. Rather it is being read as `not recognized as internal or external command operable program or batch file`.

Answer (score 122):

You can use `:sh` to exit to your default shell then typing `$ exit` at the shell prompt will return you to Vim.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this harder.  This is exactly why :shell exists.

Comment: To be fair, sometimes you want the same environment, not a sub-shell environment.  So, if you're looking for changes to environment variables for when you exit Vim completely, you'll want to CTRL-z/:sus.

Comment: Can use `$ ps` to find whether we're in a vim sub-shell before calling `$ exit` to avoid closing the terminal accidentally. Found this [here](https://joshtronic.com/2018/02/12/how-to-tell-if-your-shell-is-a-subshell-of-vim/) (I haven't tried the prompt indicator mentioned on the website).

Answer (score 38):

You can switch to shell mode temporarily by:

```
:! <command>
```

such as

```
:! ls
```

Answer (score 25):

If you are on a Unix system, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> will suspend Vim and give you a shell.

Type `fg` to go back. Note that Vim creates a swap file while editing, and suspending Vim wouldn't delete that file (you aren't exiting Vim after all). On dumb terminals, this method was pretty standard for edit-compile-edit cycles using [vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi). I just found out that for me, [gVim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29#Interface) minimizes on typing <kbd>Z</kbd>.

Answer (score 23):

You can also do that by `:sus` to fall into shell and back by `fg`.

If you frequently need to go back and forth between shell and vim, probably what you really want is have only one vim instance in the shell, and use it to open any file in the workspace. If so, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999837/how-to-open-another-file-in-background-vim-from-bash-command-line/69384250#69384250) question. Once you set it up correctly, you can `:sus` or `C-z` to return to the shell, then just `v` or `v <newfile>` to get back to vim.

And my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69384250/188326) is almost my daily routine.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using [Neovim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)#Neovim), you can do the following:

- `:terminal` command to bring up a terminal window.
- Do your terminal stuff
- Type `exit` to kill the terminal process
- Press any key to return to Neovim

Answer (score 6):

Just put in `fg` and go back to your most recently suspended program.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to exit Vim and have everything  the same when you return. There is very good documentation within Vim itself explaining the various ways this can be done. You can use the following command within vim to access the relevant help page: `:help usr_21`

To give you a brief summary, here are the different methods of quitting and returning with your session intact:

1. Suspend and resume - You don't actually quit Vim with this; you simply hide your session in the background until you need it. If you reset your computer or issue a kill command to Vim, you will lose your session. This is good for when you want to switch to another task temporarily, but if this is the case, then you might want to look into using the [GNU Screen utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) instead.
2. Sessions - This is the true way of saving your session between instances of Vim. Even if you truly quit Vim, your session will be there for you when you return. This is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

To extend [user *Zen*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879219/how-to-temporarily-exit-vim-and-go-back/1879245#1879245), you could add the following line in your `~/.vimrc` file to allow quick toggling between Bash and Vim:

```
noremap <C-d> :sh<cr>
```

Comment: five year later I just would like to mention that using C-d is  probably a bad advice as it overwrite Vim default behavior. ctrl-d scoll window towards in the buffer by default. see http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#CTRL-D

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using your mouse a little bit:

- Start your terminal,
- select a file,
- select *Open Tab*.

This creates a new tab on the terminal which you can run Vim on. Now use your mouse to shift to/from the terminal. I prefer this instead of always having to type (`:shell` and exit).