# How can I open a Shell inside a Vim Window?

Tags: vim, shell, window

I can open a shell by using the :shell command in Vim, however I can't edit a file and at the same time use the shell.

Is there any way to split Vim in many Windows (or tabs), and have a shell opened in one of them?

Comment: There used to be a shell patch out there for vim but it doesn't compile anymore afaik.  The closest you're going to get to a true shell is to use screen or tmux.  This is the biggest thing I miss in vim.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236563/how-to-run-a-terminal-inside-of-vim

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Neovim and Vim `8.2` support this natively via the `:ter[minal]` command.

See [`terminal-window`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/terminal.txt) in the docs for details.

Comment: It works, but I want to add this as a small panel at the bottom (just like VS)

Comment: @FractalSpace, to put a terminal window at the bottom (just like in VSCode), do this:  Enable mouse support with `:set mouse=a`, then create the terminal with `:terminal`.  Then put the terminal at the bottom by typing `CTRL-w` followed by a capital `J`.  Then you can use your mouse cursor to click & drag the split to wherever you like.

Answer (score 47):

Well it depends on your OS - actually I did not test it on MS Windows - but [Conque](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Conque-Shell) is one of the best plugins out there.

Actually, it can be better, but works.

Comment: If you are using Vundle to manage the plugins, you may add Bundle 'jewes/Conque-Shell' to your .vimrc file, and run :BundleInstall to install it.

Comment: One thing to look out for: The +python or +python3 requirement for vi can be a killer in some work environments.

Comment: This is the updated URL (with screenshots): https://github.com/wkentaro/conque.vim

Answer (score 19):

`:vsp` or `:sp` - splits vim into two instance but you cannot use :shell in only one of them.

Why not display another tab of the terminal not another tab of vim. If you like the idea you can try it: `Ctrl-shift-t.` and move between them with `Ctrl - pageup` and `Ctrl - pagedown`

If you want just a few shell commands you can make any shell command in vim using `!`

For example `:!./a.out`.

Comment: And to run a currently open executable you can use `vim` path magic like so: `:!./%`

Comment: _Why not display another tab of the terminal_ – not everyone is using vim in a terminal emulator above a GUI… From `Ctrl`-whatever I suppose your answer assumes gnome-terminal or a similar emulator.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `tmux` or `screen` (second is able to do only horizontal splits without a patch) to split your terminal. But I do not know the way to have one instance of Vim in both panes.

Comment: screen can do vertical splits if you build it from git.

Answer (score 8):

If you haven't found out yet, you can use the amazing [screen plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2711).

[Conque](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) is also exceptional but I find screen much more practical (it wont "litter" your buffer for example and you can just send the commands that you really want after editing them in your buffer)

Answer (score 8):

I guess this is a fairly old question, but now in 2017.  We have neovim, which is a fork of vim which adds terminal support.

So invoking `:term` would open a terminal window. The beauty of this solution as opposed to using tmux (a terminal multiplexer) is that you'll have the same window bindings as your `vim` setup.  neovim is compatible with vim, so you can basically copy and paste your `.vimrc` and it will just work.

More advantages are you can switch to normal mode on the opened terminal and you can do basic copy and editing.  It is also pretty useful for git commits too I guess, since everything in your buffer you can use in auto-complete.

I'll update this answer since vim is also planning to release terminal support, probably in vim 8.1.  You can follow the progress here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/Q9gUWGCeTXM

Once it's released, I do believe this is a more superior setup than using tmux.

Comment: It was released in Vim 8.0 I think

Answer (score 3):

Shougo's [VimShell](https://github.com/Shougo/vimshell.vim), which can auto-complete file names if used with neocomplcache

Answer (score 1):

Not absolutely what you are asking for, but you may be interested by my plugin [vim-notebook](https://www.github.com/baruchel/vim-notebook) which allows the user to keep a background process alive and to make it evaluate part of the current document (and to write the output in the document). It is intended to be used on notebook-style documents containing pieces of code to be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

With Vim 8.0 or later you can run a terminal emulator in a vim window by using the `terminal` feature. BTW if you want to simulate modern IDE terminal (like VSCode integrated terminal) in gVim or MacVim, you can put the following configuration in you `vimrc`.

```
set shell=/path/to/shell

" Make sure to replace `sh.exe` in BufNr("sh.exe") with your shell executable.
nnoremap <expr> <space> BufNr("sh.exe") > 0 ? (&buftype == 'terminal' ? '<c-^>' : ':b '. BufNr("sh.exe") . '<cr>') : ':terminal ++curwin<cr>'

function! BufNr(pattern)
  let bufcount = bufnr("$")
  let currbufnr = 1
  let nummatches = 0
  let firstmatchingbufnr = 0
  while currbufnr <= bufcount
    if(bufexists(currbufnr))
      let currbufname = bufname(currbufnr)
      if(match(currbufname, a:pattern) > -1)
        let nummatches += 1
        let firstmatchingbufnr = currbufnr
      endif
    endif
    let currbufnr = currbufnr + 1
  endwhile
  return firstmatchingbufnr
endf
```

Now you can use `space` in normal mode (or whatever mapping you chosen) to:

1. Open a terminal in current window if terminal doesn't exists yet.
2. Switch to terminal buffer if current buffer is not a terminal type.
3. Switch to previous buffer if current buffer is a terminal buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to open a "screen" program,
split screen, open shell on one and vim on another.
Works for me.

Comment: Cancelled the -1 because there was no explanation.
Besides, I tested the vim screen plugin solution and it is not that different from the solution of mrcybul.

@mrcybul : tanks for trying to help. To avoid being downvoted, read carefully the other answers and add your own only if you think it brings something new. Also include why your solution may be better in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using tmux.

Installation: sudo apt-get install tmux
Run it: tmux

Ctrl + b followed by Ctr + % : it splits your terminal window in two vertical halves.

Ctrl + "arrow left | arrow right" : moves between terminals.