# Way of opening shell within vim like emacs?

Tags: shell, vim, emacs

I want to know always enjoy the ability to open a Bash instance within Emacs. Does vim have this functionality besides the ability to run commands with :!command?

Comment: Well there's `:shell` but I'm not sure how reliable it is ...

Comment: There are some good suggestions on this related page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782752/how-can-i-open-a-shell-inside-a-vim-window

Comment: Yeah. Someone took stuff from that as answer. That is what I am looking for though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## conque

https://code.google.com/p/conque/

conque is terminal emuration.

## vimshell

https://github.com/Shougo/vimshell

vimshell is shell implement in vim.

Answer (score 2):

Conque and Vimshell are *very* limited, you might as well use `:shell` which is very reliable if you use Vim in a terminal.

Comment: I do, but was looking for an alternative.

Comment: I run repl all day in vimshell and it works great. Really nice to be able to move text between it and another buffer seamlessly. Wouldn't want to live in vimshell, but for certain tasks it is awesome!