# Does "M-x term" of emacs exist on vim?

Tags: vim, emacs, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I open a Shell inside a Vim Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782752/how-can-i-open-a-shell-inside-a-vim-window)

In emacs there is an amazing functionality that allows user to split the window into two ones and run shell commands on one window. Does it exist on vim?

Thanks

Comment: vim 8 has this functionality, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35258278/501765

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several, but [Conque](http://code.google.com/p/conque/) appears to be the most full-featured one.

Comment: Thanks for this tool, I tried it on my computer and it worked very well, however it doesn't work on my server because I can't have Python interface on it. Any help please?