# Linux shell (bash) on vi's splitview

Tags: bash, vim, shell, split, vi

I've been searching with no results for an integration of bash inside vi, as featured in emacs; the problem is: I have vi open with 2 views, one open with `:split` command, and I want to use bash through the second view, while I'm editing a file in the first; if I do `:sh` while editing the second view, the whole session pauses and a bash shell is opened, but I'm not able to edit the file and use the shell at the same time..
I don't want to use `!<command>` or external programs such as "terminator".. Is there a solution?
Thx

Comment: vi (I assume Vim) != emacs, I'm afraid - the philosophy behind the two is completely different

Comment: I know :) I would use vi because is more portable and lighter than emacs but I can't bear that there's not a feature like that :\

Comment: I think `screen(1)` is a nice solution if you're on *nix

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried looking for third-party Vim plugins? [Conque Shell](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) looks like it might do the job.

Comment: Conque shell has a few drawbacks like how everything is done in insert mode, so you have to return to normal mode before changing windows, can't enter shell then vim again...

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this feature isn't available in (presumably) Vim. It is on the list of possible new features. See here http://www.vim.org/sponsor/vote_results.php. At the current time of writing this is feature number two, add IDE features. If you want to vote for this feature you will need to sponsor Vim.

Comment: I've sponsored the vim project too, even if I've found in the ConqueShell plugin what I was looking for. Hope for an integration or implementation soon..

Comment: @Francesco this likely won't happen.  Read `:help shell-window`.  This saddens me :(

Answer (score 1):

I use VIM in conjunction with tmux, which handles window splits very well. I just transitioned to this workflow from a combination of terminal and GVIM, though, and I encountered your question in looking for a piece missing from my old workflow.

I could run GVIM from the command line with the "--servername" flag and add files to that window with the "--remote-tab" flag. Now that I'm living entirely in the terminal with tmux, I don't seem to have the same option, so BBW. :/

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote myself a plugin for that purpose, see http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4887

It won't work under Windows. On the other hand, it uses the Unix philosophy: two FIFOs, some tricky interaction between background processes. It doesn't require python or whatever. It allows to execute either a shell or any interpreter for a programming language. You can see a video of it with GNU APL working in a buffer [here](http://cjoint.com/14ma/DCmkCJGRZH7.htm).

Like IPython, you work on your own buffer and see the output in a scratch buffer.

Since I spent much time on Stackoverflow studying the answers of the three following pages:

- [Linux shell (bash) on vi's splitview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222974/linux-shell-bash-on-vis-splitview)
- [How do I run a terminal inside of Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236563/how-to-run-a-terminal-inside-of-vim)
- [Vim: Run selected code in a persistent REPL-environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906858/vim-run-selected-code-in-a-persistent-repl-environment)

I will post the same answer on the three pages; I hope nobody will be hurt by this triple post, but really they ask something close and someone else could find my answer interesting for his/her own purposes by browsing the web and finding any of these three pages.

Answer (score 0):

As a new (and maybe better) answer, may I suggest you to have a try to the amazing neovim fork of vim? It is a newer project; I tried it myself and found no compatibility issue with vim (including the use of sophisticated plugins) and it has exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

[`neovim`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim) now support terminal emulation. More details at `help nvim-terminal-emulator` in nvim