# Vim: Run selected code in a persistent REPL-environment

Tags: vim, read-eval-print-loop

R, Python, Scala etc. all come with REPL-environments, which I don't want to miss, however, most of the time editing text in them sucks, so I edit the code in vim, paste it and look at the output and edit the code in vim again.

I can run the current file with `!python %` and I can run the current line with even more vim magic, however, this will start a new process of the interpreter.

Is it possible to start a REPL and send lines of code to the running REPL (and get the results back, obviously)?

Comment: What is the magic to sent current or multiple lines and probably even Visual Select to new process ? Or the same REPL ?

Comment: @Nishant See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Execute_Python_from_within_current_file

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe one of these two plugins is what you need:

- [**slime**](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime) is [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/s/screen/)-based.
- [**tslime**](https://github.com/xaviershay/tslime.vim) is a [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/)-based version of **slime**.

Comment: Slime supports tmux, screen & whimrepl now.  It also has a much larger following.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Conque](http://code.google.com/p/conque/):

"""
Conque is a Vim plugin which allows you to run interactive programs, such as bash on linux or powershell.exe on Windows, inside a Vim buffer. 
"""

It can easily be configured to open a Python interpreter, and a key mapping can be used to transfer the current line to it to be executed (F9 for the current line, F10 for the current file etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Not for plain-python alone, but if you're using IPython 0.11 or later, take a look at [vim-ipython](https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython).

Using this plugin, you can send lines or whole files for IPython to execute, and also get back object introspection and word completions in Vim, like what you get with: `object?<enter>` and `object.<tab>` in IPython. Additionally, vim-ipython has a "shell" mode, where as you send lines to IPython, you get to see the results those lines produced back in the specialize buffer. See the [second screencast on this post](http://pirsquared.org/blog/2011/07/28/vim-ipython/)

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote a plugin for a very similar purpose: [vim-notebook](https://www.github.com/baruchel/vim-notebook) which allows the user to keep a background process alive and to make it evaluate part of the current document (and to write the output in the document). It is intended to be used on notebook-style documents containing pieces of code to be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try my plugin vim-repl. It provides a convince repl environment for vim using the vim8 terminal feature.

here is the github homepage: https://github.com/sillybun/vim-repl.

To open the repl environment, just run `:REPLToggle` or you can even bind it witk key like:

```
nnoremap <leader>r :REPLToggle<Cr>
```

To interact with repl, you just select the code and press `<leader>w`. And the code will be transmitted to the repl environment.

Look into the github homepage for more details, it will worth your time.