# Vim: map GNU Screen command

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I feel overwhelmed with the Vim docs and I can't seem to figure this out.

I want to map the <kbd>F5</kbd> key in Vim to accomplish the following actions:

1. Yank text from the visual selection in Vim.
2. Execute the yanked portion of the text in another GNU Screen session named `ipython`.

The second portion could be achieved by issuing the following command line argument (via `:!`), if only I was able to find a way to paste the register content between the double quotes of that line (but I can't figure out how):

```
map <F5> :!screen -x ipython -X stuff "[REGISTER 0 CONTENT]"<CR><CR>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check out [this previous answer of mine to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906858/vim-run-selected-code-in-a-persistent-repl-environment/7908050#7908050).

Comment: Thanks so much for this! slime.vim works exactly as advertised and does precisely what I needed. I upvoted your other answer, but you can repost here if you want me to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I copy [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906858/vim-run-selected-code-in-a-persistent-repl-environment/7908050#7908050):

Maybe one of these two plugins is what you need:

- [**slime**](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime) is [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/s/screen/)-based.
- [**tslime**](https://github.com/xaviershay/tslime.vim) is a [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/)-based version of **slime**.

Answer (score 2):

For the second part, you can use

```
:execute "!screen -x ipython -X stuff " . shellescape(@0)
```

Comment: Thanks Neil, this is really useful too.

Answer (score 1):

Given the nature of your question - I encourage you to take a look at [vim-ipython](https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython). Using this plugin, you can send lines or whole files for IPython to execute, and also get back object introspection and word completions in Vim, like what you get with: `object?<enter>` and `object.<tab>` in IPython.

If you follow that github link, there are a few screencasts demonstrating what you can do with it. It requires IPython 0.11 or later, though, with ZeroMQ enabled.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I've actually played around with your plugin already and find it excellent. I'm also doing lots of interactive data analysis with R though, so the slime solution is a one-stop shop for me. But vim-ipython will definitely stay on my radar.