# vim map long GNU Screen command

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

Hi I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014905/vim-map-gnu-screen-command) here on stackoverflow, but my question is slightly different.

When I use the following map I define a convenient map:

```
map <Leader>r :!screen -p run_and_test -X stuff '(cd /really/long/folder/data/gen_prob; epy gen_data.py)^V^V^M'<CR><CR>
```

This becames in a really long line, and I would prefer to split this by lines.
I tried with:

```
let folder = '/really/long/folder/gen_prob'
let cmd = "'(cd " . folder . "; python gen_data.py)^V^V^M'"
map <Leader>r :execute "!screen -p run_and_test -X stuff" . cmd <cr><cr>
```

but it does not work.

Any idea on how to split this initial mapping over several lines?

edit: Final solution I implemented:

```
function! Execute_screen()
  let folder = '/really/long/folder/gen_prob'
  let cmd = "'(cd " . folder . "; python gen_data.py)\r'"
  execute "!screen -p run_and_test -X stuff " . cmd
endfunction

noremap <Leader>r :call Execute_screen()<cr><cr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see much problems here except

1. The `<C-v>`: AFAIK these are characters for `:map`, not for program inside screen and thus you can remove two `^V`.
2. You forgot space after `stuff`.

There are some minor issues though:

1. Do not use `:map` if you don’t know why you are omitting `nore`. In this case you need `:nnoremap`, but `nore` version of `:map` is `:noremap`. Non-`nore` commands are bad because as the number of mappings grows chances that new mapping will screw the old one grow and this won’t be done with `nore` commands.
2. Having raw control characters in the text file is bad (they then can’t be normally viewed by `cat` and can be treated as binary files by various utilities), so use `\r` or `\<C-m>` where you have `^M` (for this purpose you can also use `\n`).

Comment: Thanks ZyX, I used your answer and implemented it in a function. I also went over my vimrc file and replaced all occurrences of map by noremap.