# How to make terminal inside vim paste from (and copy to) system's clipboard?

Tags: vim, sh, copy-paste

I am trying to run terminal inside vim and as answered here [questions/1236563](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236563/how-to-run-a-terminal-inside-of-vim) I've run `:sh`  > now  I want to paste something in `,` but when I tried CTRL+r( + regName)>  terminal turns to recursive search.... Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy to clipboard using vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961859/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-using-vim)

Comment: Also see [How can I copy text to the system clipboard from Vim?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/84/51) at the Vi and Vim Stack Exchange, which explains things in a bit more detail than the above link.