# How to switch from terminal back to editor in vim?

Tags: linux, vim

I am new to vim, and I learn that you can interact with the terminal two ways while in vim. The first is to type: ! .  The second is :term, when you have a terminal side by side with your source code.  As soon as I press :term, my cursor is in the terminal.  How do I switch back to the my source code and vice versa? The answer over here does not really help.  I tried the key combinations C-W, and then :bn but it only exits terminal, then back to terminal again.

([How do I run a terminal inside of Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236563/how-do-i-run-a-terminal-inside-of-vim))

Comment: You should ask vim questions here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MartinYork vi.stackexchange.com might be a better forum, but I don't think it's off-topic as it's a tool software developers use all the time which is clearly allowed in this forum.  Just my 2 cents. :-)

Comment: Sounds like you need practice with split screen navigation.  When one enters `:term`, vim defaults to a horizontal split screen.  If you read through the entry, `:help :split`, and practice moving between split screens, I think you will be good to go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As `:help :terminal` says, you can always exit to normal mode using `<Ctrl-\><Ctrl-N>` (`:help CTRL-\_CTRL-N`). Use `i` to return to terminal interaction.

Comment: Saved me a keystroke, since I have been using <Ctrl-W><Shift-N> until I saw this answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can swich terminal with `:shell` or `:sh` and turn back to Vim with `exit`. You can also use `C-z` and `fg` couple in same matter.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointer out, you will enter `terminal mode` after using the terminal with `:terminal`. You can use `<Ctrl-\><Ctrl-N>` to switch back to `normal mode` and then switch to your buffer with source code.

To switch to an **existing terminal** from some buffer, consider adding the following shortcut to your config :

```
" switch to an existing terminal
" by typing `<c-t>` in normal mode.
" It works by simply switching to a buffer that
" starts with the `term` keyword.
nmap <c-t> :b term<CR>i
```

In NeoVim, you can bind shortcut `<Ctrl-N>` to `<Ctrl-\><Ctrl-N>` in terminal mode to make your life easier:

```
" Escape to normal mode from inside the terminal by typing <C-n>
:tnoremap <C-n> <C-\><C-n>
```

Even better, in Neovim, you can quickly switch back to the previous buffer from the terminal with `<C-t>` with the following config:

```
" Switch back to code buffer from terminal using <C-t>
:tnoremap <C-t> <C-\><C-n> :b#<CR>
```