# Background mode for vim in windows

Tags: powershell, vim, powershell-core, powershell-7.0

I've recently started moving away from my regular editor to vim and I use powershell as my default shell. I noticed in the normal mode that pressing ctrl z allows to quickly go back to the terminal ( although in a very different mode, regular shortcuts like ctrl L to clear screen etc. weren't working ). After reading through some posts I got to know that this shortcut is meant to put vim in backgroud mode in linux and `fg` brings it back to the foreground. Since this doesn't work in powershell is there an alternative way to get the same functionality?

PS: Is there also any alternative to reach powershell prompt from within vim?

Thanks!

Comment: SO does have rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Yet, do a search for ['powershell keyboard binding vim'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+keyboard+binding+vim%27&t=hk&ia=web), you'll get several talks on the topic ov VIM and PowerShell.

Comment: I don't get what you mean? Is this a wrong question? I tried the psreadline edit mode but couldn't make much headway and there wasn't much about specifically about background mode. Can you please explain further?

Answer (score 1):

The `terminal` command can be used to reach a powershell prompt from within Vim.

```
:term powershell
```

This will open powershell in a new terminal window.

There are various ways to invoke a terminal. For example, `:tab term powershell` will open the terminal in a new tab. `:term ++curwin powershell` will open the terminal in the current window. See `:help :term` for more details.

Here is some more relevant information from a prior [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46822285/1509433):

> Using `:term` will place you in Terminal-Job mode, where you can use
> the terminal as expected.
>
> Within *Terminal-Job* mode, pressing `Ctrl-W N` or `Ctrl-\ Ctrl-N` switches the mode to *Terminal-Normal*, which
> allows the cursor to be moved and commands to be ran similarly to
> Vim's *Normal* mode. To switch back to *Terminal-Job* mode, press `i`.